# Is it possible to set the format of numbers for ASP Classic and MYSQL across multiple languages?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, multilingual

I have a classic ASP(VBscript) site that handles multiple languages. In order to do so I have set the SetLocale to the language the user requires. For example:

```
SetLocale "zh"
```

However the return from the MYSQL database would return the number in a different format depending on the Locale. English Locale (en) returns a number as 1.62, Spanish Locale (es) returns a number as 1,62

This plays havoc on the code as the commas from Spanish (1,62) absolutely destroys other functions or utilizing Highcharts where commas play a significant role. To code replace functions all over the place is risky and inefficient.

Is there a way to retain SetLocale (for date formats, month names etc.) while still enforcing numbers to follow a particular Locale or format (in my case 1.62)?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You're looking for [LCID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524330(v=vs.90).aspx).

I usually use it by setting it at the session on the Session_OnStart event, setting Session.LCID to the ID (such as 1033). [More about Session.LCID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525071(v=vs.90).aspx).

Example:

```
session.LCID = 1031
Response.Write now() & "<br>"
session.LCID = 1033
Response.Write now() & "<br>"
```

Returns:

```
14.05.2018 13:00:44
5/14/2018 1:00:44 PM
```

Comment: Are you saying I can set the Locale for dates to display dates in their language and format while still being able to format numbers in the format that I require? I.e. Spanish dates will have Spanish names but numbers will all be X.XX (rather than X,XX) ?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working @Elad? I'm working on a similar project.

Comment: No, it got too complicated. I created manual functions in order to control. The above solutions were correct, but we were dealing with an old behemoth and had to manually work through.